# Как приостановить выполнение метода в Unity (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть метод, который надо приостановить без создания корутин и т.д.

Вот пример (не оригинальный метод):

```
void method()
{
    print("start");

    // задержка

    print("end");
}
```

Как это сделать?

P.S.: не предлагайте делать это через корутины, только без корутин

Comment: Задержка по времени или до какого-то события, или что? Чем корутины не угодили?

Comment: @aepot, корутины запускаются в отдельном потоке, если бы можно было их в основном запустить...

Comment: корутины работают в том же потоке, что и скрипт, не понял проблемы

Comment: Я это имел ввиду: http://kuzinprojects.ru/Question.cs (пишу через ссылку, в комментариях код не пишется)

Comment: Перенесите ваш `end` внутрь корутины или сделайте сам `Start()` корутиной так, как показано в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы все же делал через корутины, потому что они действительно не блокируют поток, как уже указали в комментариях.

Конкретно ваш метод будет выглядеть так:

```
IEnumerator method()
{
    print("start");

    // Подождать одну секунду
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    print("end");
}
```

А запускаем его так:

```
StartCoroutine(method());
```

Comment: Я это имел ввиду: http://kuzinprojects.ru/Question.cs

Comment: @КузинАлександр да, я понял, но корутины выполняются в том же потоке.
Просто они выполняются до первой yield, а потом в каждом следующем Update() решается, можно ли продолжить выполнение (например, прошло ли N секунд), и потом корутина продолжается (в том же потоке, просто отложенное выполнение. Выполнение откладывается ровно настолько, насколько вы хотите, но при этом поток не тормозится).

Answer (score 2):

Старт сам по себе может быть корутиной. Избегать корутину бессмысленно.

```
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    Debug.Log("start");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Debug.Log("end");
}
```

Comment: корутины не могут возвращать значение

Comment: Делегаты могут!

Comment: @КузинАлександр задали бы нормальный конкретный вопрос, получили бы такой же ответ. На текущий вопрос вам дали аж 2 хороших ответа, ни один не приняли по каким-то призрачным причинам, не обозначенным в вопросе. Примите наиболее полезный ответ и задайте другой вопрос, нормально описав, что именно требуется.

Comment: @aepot, О! Ты же модера получил, поздравляю!

Comment: @Yaroslav спасибо, я мимокрокодил, смотрю - ромб лежит. Ну и поднял. :)

Comment: @Yaroslav подробнее

Answer (score -5):

В данном случае один из самых простых вариантов - поставить поток в активное ожидание

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); //millisec
```

Будьте внимательны, ведь сам поток от этого не освободит проц от нагрузки(хотя и нагрузки тут с гулькин нос), а только приостановит выполнение инструкций на 50 миллисекунд

Comment: Это вызовет фриз в игре, в Unity такое недопустимо, совсем, вообще никак.

Comment: @aepot где автор вопроса написал про игру? Автор вопроса спросил как без корутин - я ответил как без корутин и объяснил особенности

Comment: *"сам поток от этого не освободит проц от нагрузки"* - непонятно что вы имеете в виду. Можете пожалуйста уточнить?

Comment: Вот это мне и нужно, но это работает только в .NET приложениях. В unity это не работает

Comment: Так-то `Sleep` в основном потоке вообще плохая идея.. Лучше тогда просто в OnIdle (не знаю как его аналог в Unity называется) время сверять.

Comment: @Kromster , в ответе написано, что данный способ приводит к актвному ожиданию. Активное ожидание это термин с определнием, я не понимаю, что объяснить. Хорошая ли это идея или нет - в вопросе не спрашивается, я указал на особенности этого способа. То, что вы пытаетесь сказать, что это плохая идея, это подмена тезиса, в вопросе такого не спрашивалось. Считаю, что мой ответ чётко отвечает на вопрос тс и его минусят необоснованно

Comment: Я ваш тезис не подменяю, не наговаривайте ) Всего лишь добавил вопрос и комментарий.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher согласен, поэтому я плюсанул ваш ответ)) я думаю выше не критика конкретно вашего ответа, а комментарии